# Ember ArrayController content isLoaded

Tags: ember.js

How i can determine that content loaded.

```
  addEmptyShareAccounts: function(){
     debugger;
     var store = this.get('store');
     while (this.get('length') < 5) {
       this.pushObject({});
     }
   }.observes('content.isLoaded'),
```

At this point size equals to zero.

Comment: This is the right way to know the content is loaded, I don't see problem in that code. Can you show how do you fetch the data, in the route?

Comment: sorry, found the issue. It was because of caching and returning PromiseArray instead of RecordArray. But your comment helped me, thanks a lot!